# MVC w/ Entity Framework redirecting to edit page from dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Hello again stackoverflow! Newbie still learning here, I am now trying to create a small MVC with entity framework application(website?). I've gotten to the point where I can create, a new user, edit, delete them. Now I've created a new page and from a dropdownlist I want to select a persons name (that I've entered on the other base) from the database, now after the dropdownlist is populated, I want to be able to click on their name and either automatically redirect to the persons edit page, or click an edit button that takes me to their page.

[dropddownlist] < This contains the names

[John Smith 1] < Now I would click on a name, the 1 represents his student ID and both "john" and "smith" are separate parts of the table in the database.

[John Smith 1] [Edit] < now that I have his name selected in the `dropdownlist` I can click the little edit button and it takes me to another part of my little project the edit page! `localhost/employees/edit/1`

In my drop down list controller I have this (`FirstN` is First Name and `LastN` is Last Name in the database).

```
public ActionResult Index(string ddl)
{
    ViewBag.ddl = (from r in db.Students select r.FirstN + "," + r.LastN);
}
public ActionResult Edit(string ddl)
{
     Student student = db.Students.Find(ddl);
     if (student== null)
     {
         return HttpNotFound();
     }
     return View(student);
}
```

Under the view I have this

```
@Html.DropDownList("Edit", new SelectList(ViewBag.ddl));
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new SelectList(ViewBag.ddl))
```

This doesn't seem to be working and I'm not really getting anywhere. So I want to try a different approach on how to get there.

My question I'm asking help for is: I want to set their names to a value of their `studentID` (this is from the database and can't be hard coded `FirstN: John LastN=Smith StudentID=1)` but then click the edit or search button and go from `localhost/EditStudent` to `localhost/student/edit/1` and it would take you to the "John Smith" edit page.

Thanks to anyone who takes the time to read this!

Answer (score 0):

Ok... Let me explain you the way that I know.. Maybe someone else will have a more simple way...

I am explaining this without trying it in a code editor, So if there is any error that anyone notice, then please notify me.

I hope you need to get the selected value to the post method in controller.
Consider we have a Model name as Students. So getting our job done We need to create a Model as

```
public class StudentListModel
{
 public List<Student> StudentList{ get; set;}
 public SelectList StudentSelectList { get; set;}
 public int SelectedStudentId { get; set;}
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult StudentList()
{
    StudentListModel studentList = new StudentListModel();
    studentList.StudentList = //Code to load the student.
    studentList.StudentSelectList = new SelectList(studentList.StudentList, "StudentId", "StudentName");
    return View(studentList);
}
```

And in View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SelectedStudentId , Model.StudentSelectList, "Select Student")
```

Then in controller the post method will be like.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult StudentList(StudentListModel studentListModel)
{           
int SelectedStudentValue = studentListModel.SelectedStudentId;
 // Do other operations with the id
 return View();
}
```